# Raw MQ messages with WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, jms, ibm-mq

Is there a way, using MQ 7.5, to get MQ WCF to place "raw" messages into an MQ queue? It seems to be limited to SOAP-JMS formats.

By raw, I mean non-SOAP, non-JMS, non-XML, just a simple message.

MQ 8 provides this feature with `WmqStringMessage` as per [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/transmitting_non_soap_non_jms_message_pure_mqmessage_using_mq_wcf_applications?lang=en), but I'm wondering about a good way to get just a standard MQSTR-type message into an MQ queue.

Comment: Best is a relative term to be honest; what are your requirements in terms of preferred API, or is it a test administrative action?  MQPUT is one sample that can do this, the MQExplorer can send a test message. The JMS API can send raw messages quite eaisly as well.

Comment: Preferred API is to use WCF but without requiring SOAP format. We're operating at a level well above MQPUT unfortunately. I'll modify the "best" term.

Comment: Offering a bounty. I no longer care about the answer since I left the job that needed it about six months ago (solved it by bypassing WCF altogether). But it may still be useful to others, and my anal retentive nature means I *must* have an answer to all my questions :-)

Comment: By "raw" you mean bytes message?

Comment: @Shashi: yes, I just wanted something where the message format would be MQFMT_STRING or MQFMT_NONE, with an otherwise arbitrary message structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short of IBM back-porting changes from later versions of MQ to MQ7, there is no easy way to achieve this.

In the end, we ditched the use of WCF since most of the features we used are also implemented in MQ itself, such as durable transactions and guaranteed delivery.

WCF is good if you want to be able to chop and change the underlying delivery mechanisms but, if all you're using is MQ, it's easier to just code directly to that API.